# Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException in xcode

Tags: ios, macos, android-studio, flutter, dart

I move the flutter project from the window PC to Mac. I am facing error while running project in Xcode I also try flutter clean but it did not work for. I do search a lot but could not find the solution.
Is there any other way to make ipa?

```
2019-11-13 20:37:15.449711+0500 Naija TV[6295:758910]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
    2019-11-13 20:37:15.742255+0500 Naija TV[6295:758623] FirebaseAdMobPlugin <warning> [FIRApp configure]
    2019-11-13 20:37:15.748279+0500 Naija TV[6295:758623] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: '`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/.'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x1b9f2e190 0x1b91039f8 0x1b9e383b0 0x100d11fec 0x100f3790c 0x100f37644 0x100d0d0c4 0x100d0d73c 0x100d0dabc 0x1e68330f0 0x1e6834854 0x1e6839fe0 0x1e60fd2a4 0x1e610583c 0x1e60fcf28 0x1e60fd818 0x1e60fbb64 0x1e60fb82c 0x1e610036c 0x1e6101150 0x1e6100224 0x1e6104f24 0x1e68385e8 0x1e6434e04 0x1bc8aa9fc 0x1bc8b440c 0x1bc8b3c14 0x1034f8c78 0x1034fc840 0x1bc8e5040 0x1bc8e4cdc 0x1bc8e5294 0x1b9ebff2c 0x1b9ebfeac 0x1b9ebf794 0x1b9eba6d0 0x1b9eb9fc4 0x1bc0bb79c 0x1e683bc38 0x100d0dcac 0x1b997a8e0)
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Hi Danish, it looks like Xcode can't locate "GoogleService-Info.plist" which is required for Firebase initialization. Check out this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317777/could-not-find-a-valid-googleservice-info-plist-in-your-project

Comment: oh my bad. let me add this

Comment: when application run it show white screen on iPhone but it is working fine on android  os. when i click app icon it open and crash but this all code is perfectly working on android.

Answer (score 1):

The error explicitly mentions that it's unable to find the GoogleService-Info.plist file

```
could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/.
```

Alternatively, you can use [FlutterFire CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios#configure-firebase) to setup Firebase in your Flutter app. Following this guide, the plist file won't be needed to be set in your app manually anymore.