# To where do I manually copy the GoogleService-Info.plist in an Ionic project?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, ionic-framework

I've had to remove and readd iOS and it's finally building but the GoogleService-Info.plist isn't being copied to the correct location so it's failing in xCode.  Where exactly do I copy GoogleService-Info.plist to?  It's currently in my project's root folder and from what I've read it's supposed to be copied to the correct location during the build but that's not happening.

```js
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: '`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.18.0.2 - Device: iPhone 12 Pro Max (7DC46B00-B744-47FA-83D8-409FD3FC63EA) - Runtime: iOS 14.2 (18B79) - DeviceType: iPhone 12 Pro Max
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317777/could-not-find-a-valid-googleservice-info-plist-in-your-project)

Comment: @ChetanBansal my project structure in xCode doesn't have 
RenurKit
   RenurKit (subfolder)

It only has the top level folder.  But I did try to add it there but that didn't work either.

Comment: I had to add it to the Resource folder in xCode

Comment: Are you using any push notification plugin?? if yes go to plugins documentation and see where to copy this file. different plugins required different locations.

Comment: @D.Hodges you will not find the same folder - RenurKit - in your project. That is specific to your project. Make sure you are opening the `.xcworkspace` file in your ios platform folder. Check the screenshot below to verify that your project has included the file

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [this plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)

[image]

Also, you can verify it in xcode here.. the plist file entry should be pointing to the correct location here. if not, you can remove and create new entry.

[image]